# Build dynamic Lambda Expression for comparing undefined number of values

Tags: c#, lambda, csom

In short what I want do accomplish is to load Tasks from a project in SharePoint Project Server using CSOM.

```
 var projects = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Projects
        .Where(p => p.Id == projGuid)
        .Include(
            p => p.Id, p => p.Name,
            p => p.Tasks
                .Where(t => t.Id == taskGuid)
                .Include(t => t.Name))
                );

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

My Problem is with this part `.Where(t => t.Id == taskGuid)`. It works how it should if I only want to load 1 Task but would not work if I want to load more then one. Sure I could write it like that `.Where(t => t.Id == taskGuid1 || t.Id == taskGuid2 || ... )`

But that wouldn't be dynamic.

What I tried was to use an array and the look if the array `GuidArray.Contains(p.Id)`

But I get an error if I try to use `.Contains()` inside the `Where()` expression.

> ClientRequestException: The 'Contains' member cannot be used in the expression.

So I was thinking if it is possible to somehow create the lambda expression based on the number of tasks I want to load.

Comment: Can you use FirstOrDefault() and check for not null?  Or can you use Any()?

Comment: It depends how well-performing your database is, but if it's fast you could build an array with the IDs and loop trough it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regards to creation of lambda, you create the dynamic or condition you are looking for like so

```
public static class ExpressionExt
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> Where<T,TKey>(this IQueryable<T> data, string prop,params TKey[] guids)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var exp = guids.Select(g => Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, prop), Expression.Constant(g))).Aggregate((a, e) => a != null ? Expression.Or(e, a) : e);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);

            return data.Where(lambda);
        }
    }
```

And use it like `Where(nameof(A.Id), guids)` this is what I usually do when the IQueryable only supports or and not contains. There might a contains implementation there so you might want to check the documentation.